# Grouping successes in SAS on multiple rows by ID where at least 1 success counts as a success

Tags: sas, grouping, proc-sql, datastep

I'm working with a dataset of call logs and I need to summarize how many subscribers have been successfully contacted. Each row is one call, and if at least one call for a subscriber is a success, I need to set a variable that outputs "successful contact" on each row that belongs to that subscriber, even if that row does not list a successful contact. A really nice thing I'd like to do, and an ideal outcome for this problem is to output the number of successful contact that subscriber has had in the dataset on each row belonging to the subscriber, regardless of success or failure of that attempt.

Basically, it would solve my problem roughly to create this kind of output (success_contact would be the variable created):

> Subscriber ID | Name | Contact Outcome (call) | Success_Contact

> 123456        | Bob   | Unsuccessful          | Successful 
> 123456        | Bob   | Successful            | Successful 
> 123456        | Bob   | Successful            | Successful

But it would be super awesome if I could do this:

> Subscriber ID | Name | Contact Outcome (call) | Success_Contact

> 123456        | Bob   | Unsuccessful          | 2 
> 123456        | Bob   | Successful            | 2 
> 123456        | Bob   | Successful            | 2 
> 985666        | Bill  | Unsuccessful            | 0 
> 985666        | Bill  | Unsuccessful            | 0

I tried this with PROC SQL:

```
proc sql;
create  table contact_success as 
select count('Contact Outcome:'n) as no_success_outreach, 'Subscriber ID'n from work.min 
                    where 'Contact Outcome:'n = 'Successful'
                    group by 'Subscriber ID';

; 

quit;
```

But this just gave me the number of successful contacts in the whole dataset on each line.

How would I achieve my ideal outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to count the number of successful contacts for each person using PROC FREQ, and then merge the total number back in by ID.

```
data have;
   length subscriber_id $20 name $20 contact_outcome $20;
   input subscriber_id $ name $ contact_outcome $ ;
datalines;
123456 Bob Unsuccessful
123456 Bob Successful
123456 Bob Successful
985666 Bill Unsuccessful
985666 Bill Unsuccessful
;

proc freq data=have noprint;
   where contact_outcome = 'Successful';
   tables subscriber_id /missing out=counts;
run;

proc sort data=have;
   by subscriber_id;

data want (drop=count);
   merge have (in=in1)
         counts (in=in2 keep=subscriber_id count)
         ;
   by subscriber_id;
   success_contact = ifn(in2,count,0);
run;
```